# Consuming Rest API Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

i have one problem with SWIFT 3. When i consume rest api with two differents URL, for some reason this URL "http://sistemas2.laprensa.com.ni/LaPrensa/api/Beacons" not working and this URL "https://app.ccn.com.ni:8080/BeerWayNicaragua/api/BusinessType" is working. I check the JSON and is OK. Please helpme to undertand what is the problem.

No Working

```
    let url = "http://sistemas2.laprensa.com.ni/LaPrensa/api/Beacons"
    let requestURL: URL = URL(string: url)!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {data,response,error in

        if response != nil {
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments)
                    callback((json as? [[String: AnyObject]])!)
                }catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

And this is Working, only I change the URL. I don´t know what happend.

```
    let url = "https://app.ccn.com.ni:8080/BeerWayNicaragua/api/BusinessType"
    let requestURL: URL = URL(string: url)!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {data,response,error in

        if response != nil {
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments)
                    callback((json as? [[String: AnyObject]])!)
                }catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: This may be due to http and https. Did you add NSAppTransportSecurity key in your info.plist?

Comment: When you say not working are you not getting statusCode == 200 or you are not able to parse or not able to hit the API. Have you added NSAppTransportSecurity key in your info.plist?

Comment: Not related, but you don't need the `URLRequest` at all when sending a GET request. Just pass the URL. And don't use `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift. There is a native struct `URLRequest`.

Comment: your code seems to be correct so far, If any issue happens It might be in callback function, Please provide code of the callback function, if you can.

Comment: And also please be more specific about what issue you are getting?

Comment: The problem was solved by simply adding NSAppTransportSecurity key in my info.plist. I'm sorry that I'm new in Swift, and I really appreciate your help. Jitendra Solanki

Answer (score 1):

Read the console log when you try to make the request. You will notice the complain.

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

So here is the solution

Go ahead and add following key to your info.plist file vis source

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

or

[image]

From plist editor.

Comment: Please provide your comments whoever down voted this one. This is the exact problem and solution. Or if you think this is not, please provide the answer.

Comment: Waiting for the down voter comments!!!! Or get pass using whatever you want with http://. PLEASE!!

Comment: Thanks Mohammad Sadiq, you are right that this is the solution

Comment: A better solution is to make your server TLS 1.2 compliant so you don’t need to deactivate the network security

Comment: YES! When you have control over it.